# Skipping over a regex pattern contained within the pattern I'm looking for

Tags: regex

I'm parsing Pandoc-markdown files that contain footnotes starting with `^[` and ending with `]`, some of which contain embedded `[]`. For example:

```
...
to explain how the feature came to be as it is, so you can use generics more
effectively.^[Angelika Langer's [Java Generics FAQ](
www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) as well as her other
writings (together with Klaus Kreft) were invaluable during the preparation of
this chapter.]
...
```

The simple approach of (in Python):

```py
re.compile(r"\^\[.+?\]", flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Gets stopped at the first `]` and thus doesn't capture the whole footnote. Is there a way to pass over the nested `[]` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the PyPi regex module using a subroutine, you just need to be careful when setting the group boundaries:

```
import regex
text = r"""...
to explain how the feature came to be as it is, so you can use generics more
effectively.^[Angelika Langer's [Java Generics FAQ](
www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) as well as her other
writings (together with Klaus Kreft) were invaluable during the preparation of
this chapter.]
..."""
print( [x.group(1) for x in regex.finditer(r'\^(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])', text)] )
```

Output:

```
["[Angelika Langer's [Java Generics FAQ](\nwww.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) as well as her other\nwritings (together with Klaus Kreft) were invaluable during the preparation of\nthis chapter.]"]
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##TZHBasMwEETv/oohl9hNUAi9FUrIpYWml54dBxR3bYvKklmtYwf6766cNtCTVtp5Yna2u0rj3eM0mbbzLGCqaUyERsEzeLFYKKUS8aCxs9o4NH6ANISKtPRMKHVLiP0zQQcYgQlrBI@r72PPoQ@EmhyxKQNaz5RQVVEp5kL2qk753tVkzZfGu44VLwPyN33ReL0zL/uPIk2GYVD6T2pvSlX6dnNXRdFmxv7dVSOtzWZTA1k7nw0xfPTOycBGjKsDUvE1zU8YjDQ4WN0HHJgqySIWxzPuom2vz5bw2XNkbsN3TJ1mLcY7@CqRxgSUje4k2iqSmFjMLemiXFLko6rZ9126zVB5xhj//E1ZVcZ9msikvDye0mOe7p7yU5EXq9V3uttm2UORLdeYd5EVyKbpBw) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ddfpoA/1). Details:

- `\^` - `^` char
- `(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])` - Group 1:

  - `\[` - a `[` char
  - `(?:[^][]++|(?1))*` - 0 or more occurrences of:

    - `[^][]++` - one or more chars other than `]` and `[`
    - `|` - or
    - `(?1)` - Group 1 pattern
- `]` - a `]` char.